# post httpbody as json parameter swift

Tags: php, json, swift

Need to send JSON response as below format

```
[{ data =   [{
        "current_time" = "2017-08-2911:08:26";
        "imei_no" = e639e129d0f3ab7l;
        "tbl_card_type" = 0;
        "tbl_category_details" = 0;


    }];
}]
```

while using below code

```
var arrayParams : [NSDictionary] = []
   let dataValue  = ["imei_no":"e639e129d0f3b7d","current_time":"2017-08-2911:08:26","tbl_offer_details":"0","tbl_card_type":"0","tbl_dashboard":"0","tbl_category_details":"0","tbl_sub_category_details":"0"]



  let params = ["data":dataValue]
   print(params)
  arrayParams.append(params as NSDictionary )
   print(arrayParams)
```

op for parameter as below

```
[{
    data =     {
        "current_time" = "2017-08-2911:08:26";
        "imei_no" = e639e129d0f3ab7d;
        "tbl_card_type" = 0;
        "tbl_category_details" = 0;

    };
}]
```

need to add parameters like this

```
[{data = [{    "current_time" = "2017-08-2911:08:26";
        "imei_no" = e639e129d0f3ab7d;
        "tbl_card_type" = 0;
        "tbl_category_details" = 0; }];
}]
```

Comment: `let params = ["data":dataValue]` That's where lies your issue. Try `let params = ["data":[dataValue]]`, because it's an array of dictionaries.

Comment: @P.ECS did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
var arrayParams : [Any] = []
let dataValue  = ["imei_no"             :"e639e129d0f3b7d",
                  "current_time"        :"2017-08-2911:08:26",
                  "tbl_offer_details"   :"0",
                  "tbl_card_type"       :"0",
                  "tbl_dashboard"       :"0",
                  "tbl_category_details":"0",
                  "tbl_sub_category_details":"0"]



let params = ["data":[dataValue]]
print(params)
arrayParams.append(params)
print(arrayParams)
```

If you have confusion with () this you can verify by making JSON.

```
let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrayParams, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
if let json = json {
    print(json)
}
```

**NOTE: You have to use all the swift classes**

Comment: [{
    data =     (
                {
            "current_time" = "2017-08-2911:08:26";
            "imei_no" = e639e129d0f3ab7d;
            "tbl_card_type" = 0;
            "tbl_category_details" = 0;
            "tbl_dashboard" = 0;
            "tbl_like_favorite_share" = 0;
            "tbl_offer_details" = 0;
            "tbl_payment_option" = 0;
            "tbl_payment_option_provider" = 0;
            "tbl_sub_category_details" = 0;
            "tbl_user_details" = 0;
        }
    );
}]

Comment: () this is array in the swift and is equal to [] in JSON.

Comment: how can i put value data = instead  if as dict data : which i am getting in jsonres[
  {
    "data" : [
      {
        "tbl_user_details" : "0",
        "current_time" : "2017-08-2911:08:26",
        "imei_no" : "e639e129d0f3ab7d",
        "tbl_offer_details" : "0",
        "tbl_card_type" : "0",
        "tbl_payment_option" : "0",
        "tbl_payment_option_provider" : "0",
        "tbl_category_details" : "0",
        "tbl_dashboard" : "0",
        "tbl_sub_category_details" : "0",
        "tbl_like_favorite_share" : "0"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: Could you please give more clarification about this?